# saving image view to a coreData entity (swift4)

Tags: ios, image, core-data, uiimageview, swift4

I am trying to save whatever is on a image view to core data. Right now I have a successfully working system of core data. That takes whatever is in a textfield and places it to core data as a string. I would like to do the exact same thing only with the imagview known as imageV. I don't think the question is a repeat because this is in swift 4 and I want to keep the same code framework just change the string in the core data entity to whatever I need to store images.

COREDATAVC

```
import UIKit 
import CoreData
class cdHandler: NSObject {

    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appdeleagetzz = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appdeleagetzz.persistentContainer.viewContext

    }

    class func saveObject(userName: String) -> Bool {
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)

        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        managedObject.setValue(userName, forKey: "userName")


        do {
            try context.save()
            return true

        } catch {
            return false

        }
    }


    class func fetchObject() -> [User]? {

        do {
            let context = getContext()
            return try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            return [User]()
        }
    }

}
```

ENTERING DATA VC

```
import UIKit

class editVCViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageV: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func magicJohnson(_ sender: Any) {

        let d = self.imageV.image
   let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(d!)
    }}}
```

[image]

Comment: You need a binary attribute.  You can't save a `UIImageView`, but you can save the `UIImage` it is showing;  You need to convert the image to `Data` using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @TomHarrington I just updated my question. Right now my code uses coreData as a string and works. I need to convert that string code to a binary data code. Specifically class func saveObject(userName: String) -> Bool.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just updated my question. Right now my code uses coreData as a string and works. I need to convert that string code to a binary data code. Specifically class func saveObject(userName: String) -> Bool.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, create a binary attribute in your Core Data entity and then assign the data for your image to it.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok what do I do with Specifically class func saveObject(userName: String) -> Bool. I can change userName: String to userName: BinaryData.

Comment: `managedObject.setValue(data, forKey:"binaryAttribute")`

Comment: @Paulw11 will class func saveObject(userName: String) -> Bool. I can change userName: String to userName: BinaryData. Work even though I am not attempting to save  String?

Comment: Not BinaryData; `Data`

Comment: @Paulw11 you the man. Its starting to work. So could I display binary data on a image view.

Comment: You need to convert the data you back into a `UIImage` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624106-init First

Comment: @Paulw11 can you take at a look this question

Comment: @Paulw11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698459/display-binary-data-on-image-view-swift4 this is the question.